# Getting form data into PHP for a SQL query for chart.js

Tags: php, html, mysql, chart.js

I'm working on a project and I've been learning several new languages through numerous tutorials. I think I am now at a point where I am stuck.

Basically, what I have now is a SQL query written in PHP that is sent to a JS function to use in Chart.js. I can also fill out my  dropdown using php. Everything up to here works, as it properly displays a chart of the hardcoded county.

My next step is to be able to display the chart according to the dropdown selection, which I can't seem to do.

Here is my working code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Maybe this works
    </title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="../Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="query2.php">
        <select id="selectCounty" name="county"> 
        <!--Fill out the dropdown with counties-->
        <?php
            require("Database.php");
            require("Utils.php");
            $db = Database::getConnection();
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT county FROM STI";
            $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute();
            $statement->bind_result($county);
            while($statement->fetch()){
                echo "<option value='$county'>$county</option>\n\t\t\t";
            }
            $statement->close();
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton"/>
    </form>
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="chart" width="960px" height="480px"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="graph2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my querying file:

```
<?php
require("Database.php");
require("Utils.php");
$db = Database::getConnection();
$co = $_POST['county'];
consoleLog($co);
$sql = "SELECT county, disease, count, year FROM STI WHERE county=\"$co\"";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($county, $disease, $count, $year);
$statement->store_result();
$ar = array();

$diseases = ["Chlamydia", "Gonorrhea", "Total Early Syphilis", "HIV/AIDS"];

while($statement->fetch()){
    $county = trim($county);
    $contained = false;
    foreach($ar as $c){
        if($county == $c[0]){
            $contained = true;
            $ar[getCountyIndex($ar, $county)][getIndex($diseases, $disease) + 1][getYearIndex($year)] = $count;
        }
    }
    if($contained == false){
        $ar[] = [$county, array_fill(0, 10, -1), array_fill(0, 10, -1), array_fill(0, 10, -1), array_fill(0, 10, -1)];
        $ar[getCountyIndex($ar, $county)][getIndex($diseases, $disease) + 1][getYearIndex($year)] = $count;
    }
    unset($c);
}
print json_encode($ar);
$statement->close();

function getIndex($_ar, $_key){
    for($_i = 0; $_i < count($_ar); $_i++){
        if($_ar[$_i] == $_key){
            return $_i;
        }
    }
}
function getCountyIndex($_ar, $_county){
    for($_i = 0; $_i < count($_ar); $_i++){
        if($_ar[$_i][0] == $_county){
            return $_i;
        }
    }
}
function getYearIndex($_year){
    return $_year - 2006;
}
?>
```

And JS file:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url : "https://sexspecs-cptcomo.c9users.io/Tut/query2.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var d = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(d[0][0]);
        var dat = {
            counties: [],
            chl : [],
            gon : [],
            tes : [],
            hiv : [],
        };
        for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
            dat.counties.push(d[i][0]);
            dat.chl.push(d[i][1]);
            dat.gon.push(d[i][2]);
            dat.tes.push(d[i][3]);
            dat.hiv.push(d[i][4]);
        }
        console.log(dat);

        var chartData = {
            labels: [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Gonorrhea",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    fillColor : "rgba(0,194,132,0.2)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    data: dat.gon[0]
                }, 
                {
                    label: "Chlamydia",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    fillColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.2)",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                    data: dat.chl[0]
                }, 
                {
                    label: "Total Early Syphillis",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    fillColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.2)",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.75)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(35, 35, 35, 1)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(35, 35, 35, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(35, 35, 35, 1)",
                    data: dat.tes[0]
                }, 
                {
                    label: "HIV/AIDS",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    fillColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.75)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(0, 200, 0, 1)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 200, 0, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0, 200, 0, 1)",
                    data: dat.hiv[0]
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartData,
        })
    },
    error : function(data) {
        console.log("ERROR");   
    }
})
})
```

This code displays the data for the county of Fairfax. I want to display data according to the select dropdown. I tried putting `$_POST['county']` in the querying php file, but it didn't receive anything. I then tried it with the select encapsulated in a form tag with attributes `method="POST"` and `action="querying2.php"`, but that didn't work either as it would just redirect me to the querying2.php file. I removed the action attribute, but then it would redirect me to a URL with `?=county=Fairfax+` appended to the end, with no chart.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have to replace `WHERE county=\"Fairfax\"` with the variable you supply.

Comment: Assuming that the variable I wish to supply is $_POST['county'], as it is the name of my select tag, I end up getting a blank string which causes the query to fail.

Comment: How do you submit the value of your html to PHP?

Comment: The form method must be "post" and then you should use your prepared statement by passing the value of `$_POST['county']` to the query.

Comment: @JayBlanchard In the last part of my post, I have mentioned that I tried putting my select and input button tags into a form tag with `method="post"` to no avail. I have also added in `$_POST["county"]` in place of `Fairfax`. What this ended up doing is absolutely nothing, since my `query2.php` file gets an empty string in place of the `$_POST["county"]` call.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Jquery is definitely included as it works with the county hardcoded in. This is the error message that I get in the AJAX request: `graph2.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.success (graph2.js:8)
    at j (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:4)`

Comment: The `console.log` of the data array that is passed in is simply an empty array: `[]` which indicates that the query failed. I have a testing consoleLog for php, and using that, I can see that `$_POST['county']` is empty.

Comment: @JayBlanchard So I tried putting in `action="query2.php"` in my form. `$_POST['county']` is now getting the correct values; however, a problem is that now I am getting redirected to query2.php, when I want to stay on my original page in order to see the graph.

Comment: Prevent the default event, change `$("#submitButton").click(function(){` to `$("#submitButton").click(function(event){` then the first line of the click function should be `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have edited the post to show the code I have now. I am still getting some weird behavior. After adding in `event.preventDefault()`, I now don't get redirected to the query2.php file, but the error message shown above returns as I get an empty array for `data`. If I comment out `event.preventDefault()`, I can log to the console the `$co` variable, which correctly holds the county chosen as well as successfully completing the query with chosen county; however, I get redirected to query2.php

Comment: Look in the console now and watch the request / response

Comment: Here is my complete console response: Line 7 of graph2.js: `[]`. This is the empty array of data that I mentioned that is being passed in. Line 9 of graph2.js: `graph2.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.success (graph2.js:9)
    at j (jquery.js:3099)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3211)
    at x (jquery.js:8264)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:8605)` This is when I try to log `data[0][0]`, which holds the county name when it works. Clearly it fails because the array is empty. There is no more output.


​

Comment: @JayBlanchard What reponse should I be expecting?

Comment: Look at your Network tab in the developer tols and run the script. There is a request and response. That should fail if your county is empty and it will be because you're not sending the data in your AJAX request. `url : "https://sexspecs-cptcomo.c9users.io/Tut/query2.php",
    type : "post",data: {county : county}` for example. You will have to get the value of the drop-down into a variable which can be used by the AJAX request. For example `var county = $('[name="county"]').val();`

Comment: [Have a look at this.](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I added in your recommendations and they seem to have worked! I'll make sure to read up more on this to make sure that I fully understand what's going on. Thank you for your help and your patience

Comment: You bet @Kevin! Glad to have helped!

Comment: @JayBlanchard you wanna help someone out having a similar problem to this? XD

Comment: @KebabProgrammer I am always glad to help. Have you posted a question?

Comment: It wasn't me who needed the help, but I can provide a link to the chat, the person that needs the help is fairly new to programming.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885152/chart-to-update-from-a-drop-down-selection-and-mysql-query is the question

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188991/discussion-between-kebab-programmer-and-danny is the chat