# Chart to update from a drop down selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, chart.js

I have a javascript file `app.js` and a php file `data.php`.

`app.js` creates a graph using data from the JSON output of`data.php`.

See `app.js`below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var op1 = [];
      var op2 = [];

      let data_keys = Object.keys(data[0])
      console.log(data_keys)
      first = data_keys[0] //1st element
      second = data_keys[1] //2nd element

       for(var i in data) {
            op1.push(data[i][first])
            op2.push(data[i][second])

               }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: op1,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'SystemID and Apparent Power (VA)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 50, 50, 0.4)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(500, 50, 50, 0.5)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(500, 30, 30, 0.2)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(500, 30, 30, 0.3)',
            data: op2
          } 
        ]
      };

      var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');

      var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata,
        options: {
        scales: {
           xAxes: [{
                   ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10
                   }
                  }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10
                }
            }]
                }
             }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

The code above is all working fine, I am able to see a graph using the queried data from my data.php.

Part of `data.php` is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT SystemID, ApparentPower FROM RaritanMachineDataa";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$data = array(); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $row);
    $data[] = $row;
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Now I want to have a drop down menu below my graph and I want to be able to choose from any of the options and send these options to my data.php SELECT query and update the graph. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addData` and `removeData`, see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html. `addData` adds only one dataset per call, but `removeData` removes all datasets from chart. There is also way to push label and dataset see codepen sample: https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/bqaGRR.

First what you need is to save your chart in variable, so you can easy add and remove data. when you have chart saved in var, let's say `myChart`, you can call `removeData()` like: `myChart.removeData()`. For adding data you have to send label and data like: `myChart.addData('news', [2, 32, 3])`.

The idea is next, to update chart when your ajax call is success. The important thing is to have chart instance in same file where you have ajax call, you should move onclick call to js file, or call function from from `àpp.js`.

Now depends on your data structure, you will need to go through each and get value and label. You have to get same result from data like you have when you're creating chart.

**CODE SAMPLE:**

What you will have in `app.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var op1 = [];
            var op2 = [];

            let data_keys = Object.keys(data[0])
            console.log(data_keys)
            first = data_keys[0] //1st element
            second = data_keys[1] //2nd element

            for(var i in data) {
                op1.push(data[i][first])
                op2.push(data[i][second])

            }

         var chartdata = {
         labels: op1,
         datasets : [
             {
             label: 'SystemID and Apparent Power (VA)',
             backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 50, 50, 0.4)',
             borderColor: 'rgba(500, 50, 50, 0.5)',
             hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(500, 30, 30, 0.2)',
             hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(500, 30, 30, 0.3)',
             data: op2
         } 
         ]
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');

  var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartdata,
    options: {
    scales: {
       xAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                fontSize: 10
               }
              }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 10
            }
        }]
            }
         }
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
    });

    function updateChartAjaxCall(data1, data2)
    {
        //ajax call here 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'data.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {data1:data1,data2:data2},
            success:function(data){ 
                // here also manipulate data what you get to update chart propertly
                myChart.removeData();
                myChart.addData('newLabel', [23, 33, 4]);
            }, 
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
            }, 
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

Then you `bargraph.html` will be also changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submitButton').click(function(e){
    var data1=$("#data1").val();
    var data2=$("#data2").val();

    updateChartAjaxCall(data1, data2);
});
</script>
```

Comment: ok hmm based on my code right now. In my `app.js` file, can I somehow use ajax to grab the values 'data1' & 'data2' from `bargraph.html`. If so, could you show me how

Comment: Well, I suppose that you have included `app.js` to `bargraph.html`? If yes, then you can in this file reach all html elements. you could do it on same way to get values from element or you can add new function in `app.js` which you will call from `bargraph.html` in onclick event for submit button, end send selected values as params to function in `app.js`. I can also edit answer with example code.

Comment: yes if you could edit answer with example code would be helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: can we talk in chat

Comment: Sorry, not available now for chat. Write down here in comment questions or update your question with general questions what you want to know, I'm going to explain you all.

Comment: I have two separate files `app.js` and `bargraph.html`. See code in my original post. If you see my ajax post in `bargraph.html`, is it possible to just pass those data values to my `app.js` file using just ajax? I just simply want the values to be passed from `bargraph.html` to `app.js`.

Comment: well, you can't just send to js file from ajax, but what you can is to call ajax in `app.js`, there you can also access your html values, like you have done already in `bargraph.html`. There is a way to have global js values and update them on ajax call, but anyway again you need to have function in `app.js` which you will call after ajax call, but better no!(thing with async call can just mix data). So best way is like I've suggested already with function in `app.js`

Comment: I can't get it to work :( I feel I am not adding the code in the correct place. I have edited my post with full `app.js` if you could show what I need to replace or remove while implementing your way please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189082/discussion-between-alien-and-danny).

Comment: still need help if we can chat