# Passing function parameters

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters

I have a `bargraph.html` file and a seperate `app.js` file. I am trying to pass a variable named `data` which contains values in my `bargraph.html` and I want to pass it to my `app.js` file.

Part of my `app.js` file

```
function passfunction(data) {
            return data
            console.log(data)
        }

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(passfunction.data);
```

Part of my `bargraph.html` file

```
<form method="POST" name="dataform" action="" id='dataForm'>
  <select id="data1" name="data1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="ApparentPower">ApparentPower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="data2" name="data2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="ApparentPower">ApparentPower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="submitButton" name="submitButton">Submit</button>
 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submitButton').click(function(e){



      var data1=$("#data1").val();
      var data2=$("#data2").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'data.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {data1:data1,data2:data2},
            success:function(data){ 
                passfunction(data);
                console.log(data);
```

In my `bargraph.html`, in `console.log(data)`, it is displaying the right data that I want to use in my `app.js` file. However I am unable to pass it correctly to my `app.js`.

Currently when I run my code, in `app.js` in line `console.log(passfunction.data);,` it is displaying `undefined` in my console. It should be displaying the same data from `bargraph.html` `console.log(data)`.

Why is this? What am I doing wrong? I need some assistance please

The suggested answer is not relevant to my question

Comment: is `app.js` included in bargraph.html?

Comment: @devpro yes app.js is included in my .html

Comment: is it dummy? `function passfunction(data) {
            return data
            console.log(data)
        }`

Comment: @devpro sorry don't know what you mean dummy?

Comment: where u define `data1` ?? `data2`?

Comment: According to your post from yesterday, your bargraph JS doesn't run until something is clicked? But your app.js runs as soon as the page has loaded, so the data it probably unavailable.

Comment: your console showing u undefine, but undefine what?

Comment: @devpro see my updated code .

Comment: @JonStirling Yeah but i've clicked on the options from drop down and it's returning undefined in my console from app.js as i've mentioned in my post

Comment: Yeah, because app.js already ran before you clicked the button.

Comment: @JonStirling How can I sort this out :o

Comment: Not sure since I can't work out what you're actually trying to do with the code you've got.  The simplest way I guess is to put the app.js bit in a function, then call that function in the success part of the AJAX call in bargraph. But for a more robust set of options, see the duplicate link.

Comment: @JonStirling I am creating a graph in my app.js file, I want to be able to choose from the drop down menu and pass the values from "data" in my bargraph.html file to my app.js file to use and redraw the graph.. what is the simplest way for this.

Comment: `passfunction.data` is `undefined`, why wouldn't it be? If you want to call `passfunction` with `data` as the parameter you write `passfunction(data)`

Comment: @Lennholm I have tried this just now and still `console.log(passfunction(data));` is displaying "undefined" in browser console.

Comment: @Lennholm *correction, it is not displaying undefined now, but it is displaying my html file in text??

Comment: @Danny Because that's what `data` is, the response to your AJAX request. Make sure you're making your request properly (correct URL, the correct HTTP method, etc).

Comment: @Lennholm can we chat please?

Comment: @Danny Sorry, I don't have the time for chat. But please post the entire code of your `$.ajax()` call in the question, the way you've cut it off in the middle of the success callback makes it very difficult to help you.

Comment: @Lennholm please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885152/chart-to-update-from-a-drop-down-selection